# How to call a JavaScript function after n seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to call a javascript function from a div every seconds. and i also pass arguments with this function

```js
function myFunc(a) {
    alert(a);
    setInterval("myFunc(a)", 1000); 
}
myFunc(a);
```

```html
<div myFunc(5)></div>
```

Comment: You have to use jquery setTimeout function. You want the timeout approach?

Comment: @SorangwalaAbbasali Why would you need JQuery for that?

Comment: `<div myFunc(5)>` this doesn't make any sense

Comment: if you had called... then it would generate infinate tymes of interval instances recursively

Comment: and why from div you want to call means how on click, on hover or something else ?

Comment: @rahul_m i want to update div data every seconds

Comment: ok, update means what you actually want to do with that div ? means wana show something inside that, or some other stuff, in short, make clearity to depth

Comment: @rahul_m  
see this fiddle i want to pass the class name https://jsfiddle.net/11dtm7ck/2/

Comment: Ok, so, its working right ?

Comment: @rahul_m no its not. its load the duplicate value of one another

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript Window setInterval() Method [see](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval)

```
<button onclick="myFunction('param')">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction(a) {
   setInterval(function(){ alert(a); }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/tocixafuxu/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code where page will be auto refreshed after 1min and that time on page load you are calling your function

```
 var refresh_mili_sec=60000;  //60000=1min
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var a=5;
    myFunc(a);

     setTimeout(function()
        {
             window.location.reload(1);
         }, refresh_mili_sec);
    });

    function myFunc(a) {
        alert(a);
      }
```